# AWS DMS Hash column content in existing column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, sqlite, aws-dms

I have two identical databases, with two identical tables. The source database's table has data and the target database's table has no data.

The tables in both databases are named `testt`.

What the data looks like now in the source database

```
id   name
----------
1    tim
2    bob
3    john
```

What I want the `testt` table to look like after the migration:

```
id   name
---------------------------
1    0wg9jg-wjeigwg-jieg
2    jwigj-iwjgw-ijgg
3    wjeoiweg-wjegiweg-jei
```

I just need the content of the `name` column in `testt` on the target database to be hashed (or any uuid is fine).

My attempt:

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule-type": "selection",
      "rule-id": "1",
      "rule-name": "SelectTable",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "public",
        "table-name": "testt"
      },
      "rule-action": "include"
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "2",
      "rule-name": "HashNameColumn",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "public",
        "table-name": "testt",
        "column-name": "name"
      },
      "rule-action": "transform",
      "expression": "sha256($column)",
      "rule-description": "hasing on the name column"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I use this on AWS's console it just gives a super generic invalid expression error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using an undocumented function. I bet you can use `hash_sha256(x)` instead. See [hash_sha256()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Expressions.html)